# bold text in dynamically created table - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add bold text to the table header row using the .bold() method in javascript. The table is created dynamically using this code:

```
var table = document.getElementById('changestable');
    var titlerow = ["Type", "Change Date", "FCM", "Hull ID", "Name", "Length", "Manufacturer", "Manufacturer ID", "Year", "Value", "Owner", "Loss Payee", "Policy ID", "Start Date", "End Date"];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
    for (k = 0; k < titlerow.length; k++){
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(k);
        var newText = document.createTextNode(titlerow[k]);
        newCell.appendChild(newText);
    }
```

I have tried:

```
.bold() // and this just adds <b></b>, not actually making the text bold
```

I have also tried:

```
titlerow[k].style.fontWeight = 'bold'
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply a `style` to a string - you have to apply it to an element instead.

```
newCell.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

But instead of trying to mess with it in Javascript, why not apply the style in CSS instead? Separate Javascript functionality from page styling

```js
var table = document.getElementById('changestable');
var titlerow = ["Type", "Change Date", "FCM", "Hull ID", "Name", "Length", "Manufacturer", "Manufacturer ID", "Year", "Value", "Owner", "Loss Payee", "Policy ID", "Start Date", "End Date"];
var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
for (k = 0; k < titlerow.length; k++){
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(k);
  var newText = document.createTextNode(titlerow[k]);
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
```

```css
#changestable tr:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="changestable"></table>
```

Or, even better, if possible, insert `th`s rather than `td`s, and you won't have any need of styling at all, since `th`s are bolded automatically:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('changestable');
var titlerow = ["Type", "Change Date", "FCM", "Hull ID", "Name", "Length", "Manufacturer", "Manufacturer ID", "Year", "Value", "Owner", "Loss Payee", "Policy ID", "Start Date", "End Date"];
var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
titlerow.forEach(titleStr => {
  newRow.appendChild(document.createElement('th'))
    .textContent = titleStr;
});
```

```html
<table id="changestable"></table>
```

Comment: thank you very much! CSS styling isn't my strong suite.

Comment: actually did you place this CSS in the style.css or within the function ?

Comment: In CSS, of course - CSS syntax inside of JS is invalid. Press "Run code snippet"

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML and add `<b>` tag

```
for (k = 0; k < titlerow.length; k++){
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(k);
    var newText = document.createTextNode();
    newText.innerHTML = `<b> ${titlerow[k]} </b>`;
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
}
```

Comment: That's invalid, text nodes cannot be styled like that. (no `style` property)